# How to understand this sentence on a proper subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Bertsimas & Tsitsiklis's Intro to Linear Optimization. One sentence in the proof of Theorem 2.3 says "[If] vectors $a_i, i\in I$, lie in a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, [then] there exists some nonzero vector $d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a_i^\prime d=0$ for all $i\in I$." How to understand this briefly? Thanks.

Comment: If $S$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then it is contained in some hyperplane of dimension $n-1$. Let $d$ be a normal to the hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks, @copper.hat.